# video normalization with ffmpeg

Tags: video, image-processing, ffmpeg

Is there anyway to use ffmpeg script to normalize a video luma to its complete dynamic range? I have been trying to do this with lutyuv like this:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf lutyuv=y='((val - minval)*255)/(maxval - minval)' output.mp4

but the output video is just exactly the same as the input. (I am sure the input does not use it's complete dynamic range)

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=out_range=full -color_range 2 -pix_fmt yuvj420p output.mp4
```

I believe that since your input is flagged as limited and no range is set for output, FFmpeg probably rescales the filter output.

The `scale` filter with `out_range=full` expands the values to `0-255`. `color_range 2` tags the output as full range. `-pix_fmt yuvj420p` is just put in there as a safety in case FFmpeg sees the pixel format is the default `yuv420p` and auto-compresses the range. `yuvj420p` is `yuv420p` with full range. This used to be an issue earlier, but shouldn't be now.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, Actually I tried your command but it's changing nothing ! Here is a link to the video if you would like to check https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9ooyxrslles5nii/AABr1PlOBuVAZdvxPT8FDeVWa?dl=0

Comment: If you run the following command, you'll see that your out3 mp4 is full range: `ffmpeg -ss 5 -i out3.mp4 -vf signalstats,metadata=print -vframes 1 -f null -` See the value of  `lavfi.signalstats.YMAX` in the readout. It's 255. That's full range. The problem looks here to be gamma. Use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "eq=gamma=1/2.2" output.mp4`

Comment: Yeah, YMAX is 255 but YMIN is not 0, is there anyway to let YMIN be zero in order to use the whole dynamic range?

Comment: If the source video has no black pixels, then there will be no pixel with Y=0 even in full range. You can try to forcibly expand the luminance with the pp filter i.e. `pp=al:f`

Comment: I wondering also that it might be able to expand the dynamic range using:
-vf lutyuv=y='((val - YMIN) * 255) / (YMAX - YMIN)).
But is there any way to extract only the value of YMIN and YMAX from the signalstats command instead of printing all the statistics ?

Comment: There is. On Windows, it would be `ffmpeg -ss 5 -i out3.mp4 -vf signalstats,metadata=print -vframes 1 -f null - 2>&1 | findstr YM` But this would be different each frame. The `pp=al:f` does the same thing as your lut expr.

Comment: I tried to use `lutyuv` solution and it worked, however 
`ffmpeg -i out3.mp4 -vf pp=al:f  out.mp4`
did not really work, the video would still be so bright :( you can check it for yourself

Comment: @Alan_AI as of 2018 there is a "normalize" ffmpeg filter which normalizes RGB video to its full dynamic range. The effect should be similar to normalizing luma of YUV video. It may be of interest if this 2-year-old question is still relevant to you!